# Integers that are not divisible by several numbers

Tags: r

I am trying to print a vector with the integers between 1 and 100 that are not divisible by 2, 3 and 7 in R.

I tried `seq` but I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: just out of curiosity: is this homework, or self-study?

Comment: OP said in another (dup) q that it was homework. I'd like to "meet" the instructor who thinks this is a good way to teach R.

Comment: it's not a terrible exercise.  I often ask students to write R code to select the odd or even elements of a vector (obviously more generally useful than this, but not that different ...)

Comment: Doesn't focusing on `for` (esp for folks new to both R & programming) ultimately slow down how well they grok vectorized operations? Perhaps I've just seen too many `for` loop questions on SO (which is a place, by definition, where folks that may be having issues groking something are going to go).

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use `Filter` to, well, *filter* the sequence for any number that meets your condition:

```
Filter(function(i) { all(i %% c(2,3,7) != 0) }, seq(100))
## [1]  1  5 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 55 59 61 65 67 71 73 79 83 85 89 95 97
```

Note that while this may (IMO) be the most readable, it's the worst in terms of performance (so far):

**UPDATED** to take into account rawr's `for` loop solution:

```
microbenchmark(
  filter={ v1 <- seq(100); Filter(function(i) { all(i %% c(2,3,7) != 0) }, v1) },
  reduce={ v1 <- seq(100); v1[!Reduce(`|`,lapply(c(2,3,7), function(x) !(v1 %%x)))] },
  rowout={ v1 <- seq(100); v1[rowSums(outer(v1, c(2, 3, 7), "%%") == 0) == 0] },
  looopy={ v1 <- seq(100); for (ii in c(2,3,7)) v1 <- v1[-which(v1 %% ii == 0)]; v1 },
  times=1000
)

## Unit: microseconds
##    expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
##  filter 108.280 118.7000 143.88592 126.2155 136.6290 2349.952  1000   c
##  reduce  21.552  23.8095  25.91997  24.8150  25.8580  144.067  1000 ab 
##  rowout  26.075  28.4920  31.11812  29.5350  31.2125  184.225  1000  b 
##  looopy  14.149  16.0765  18.11806  16.8995  17.8595  160.485  1000 a
```

To make it fair I added sequence generation to all of them (and, I was doing this to compare relative performance vs actual speed anyway, so the comparison results still work).

Original statement:

*"Unsurprisingly, akrun's is optimal :-)"*

is now superseded by:

*"Unsurprisingly, rawr's is optimal :-)"*

Comment: what about a simple loop `loop = {v1 <- 1:100; for (ii in c(2,3,7)) v1 <- v1[-which(v1 %% ii == 0)]; v1}` seems fastest for me

Answer (score 5):

We can do this in a loop using `lapply` using the modulo operator, convert the 0 to TRUE  by negating (`!`), use `Reduce` with `|` to find the corresponding `list` elements that are either TRUE, negate and subset the 'v1'

```
v1[!Reduce(`|`,lapply(c(2,3,7), function(x) !(v1 %%x)))]
```

Or instead of looping, this can be also done in a faster way.

```
 v1[!(!v1%%2) + (!v1%%3) + (!v1%%7)]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- seq(100)
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically you want to compute each of the numbers in `1:100` modulo 2, 3, and 7. You could use `outer` to perform all the modulo operations in a single vectorized operation, using `rowSums` to identify the elements in `1:100` that are not perfectly divided by 2, 3, or 7.

```
v1 <- 1:100
v1[rowSums(outer(v1, c(2, 3, 7), "%%") == 0) == 0]
#  [1]  1  5 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 55 59 61 65 67 71 73 79 83 85 89 95 97
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are better, but if you really need to use a `for` loop, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198902/4770166) suggests, this could be a possibility:

```
x <- vector()
n <- 1L
for(i in 1:100){if (i%%2!=0 & i%%3!=0 & i%%7!=0) {x[n] <- i;  n <- n+1}}
#> x
# [1]  1  5 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 55 59 61 65 67 71 73 79 83 85 89 95 97
```

As already mentioned, the other answers posted here are better because they exploit the vectorized capabilities of R. The short code shown here is probably slower than any of the other answers and more complicated to maintain. It is the typical syntax of other programming languages, like C or FORTRAN, applied to R. It works, but it is not the way things should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using modulo arithmetic explicitly, we can generate the negative modulo sequence easily by counting down. Then for each of the three sequences, we can OR them all together, then drop it into `which()`.

```
 which(as.logical(pmin(rep_len(1:0, 100), 
                       rep_len(2:0, 100),
                       rep_len(6:0, 100))))
```

If we want to be a bit less hardcoded, we might use `do.call` with `lapply()`:

```
which(as.logical(do.call(pmin, lapply(c(2,3,7)-1, function(x)rep_len(x:0, 100)))))
```

EDIT:

Here's one way to do it using logicals:

`v1 <- logical(100); for (ii in c(2,3,7) -1) v1 <- v1 | rep_len(rep(c(F,T), c(ii,1)), 100) ; which(!v1)`

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem in my class. I assumed the teacher gave me all the information I needed to find the answer and I was correct. This is week one and all that other silly stuff all you other advanced people used has not came up.
I did this though.

```
r = c(1:100)
which(r %% 3 == 0 & r %% 7 == 0 & r %% 2 == 0)
```

Use the `which` function.

Comment: I'd hold off on calling other answers silly—the correct answers have 28 elements, whereas yours has 2. Yours also only works as expected if the vector happens to be a continuous sequence starting at 1, because it just returns indices, it doesn't actually subset the vector *by* the matching indices